# Can I short R to G in order to manually turn on the fan?

Tags: wiring, furnace

I'm replacing a faulty Aprilaire humidistat with a Arduino driven home automation system. I want to be able to have the Arduino turn the house fan on and off. If I jump the R to the G wire (or use a relay to connect the two), will it turn on the fan, or will I just burn out my furnace controller?

Comment: YES you can do that, since the thermostat does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red(R) wire will be your 24vac supply, connecting that to the green(G) wire will start your fan. That's all your thermostat is doing is making that connection. It won't hurt your controller. Connecting R to C will short your transformer.

Comment: Thank you for the warning about connecting R to C! I really appreciate your help!